# Permalink options page corrupts web.config file

Tags: permalinks

Whenever I got to http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/options-permalink.php my config file at http://example.com/wordpress/web.config instantly gets corrupt and I have to delete the config file. What could be causing this? I am using the newest version of Wordpress and am running it on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: When visiting that page it would actually create an empty config file. To fix the issue, I copied the config file from my http://example.com/ directory to the wordpress one, it works fine now.

Comment: please post that as a detailed answer as it could be helpful to others. :) Then don't forget to delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

When visiting that page it would actually create an empty config file. To fix the issue, I copied the config file from my http://example.com/ directory to the http://example.com/wordpress/ one, it works fine now.